# BERT-based NER model giving inconsistent prediction when deserialized

Tags: python, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to train an NER model using the HuggingFace transformers library on Colab cloud GPUs, pickle it and load the model on my own CPU to make predictions.

**Code**

The model is the following:

```
from transformers import BertForTokenClassification

model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-cased",
    num_labels=NUM_LABELS,
    output_attentions = False,
    output_hidden_states = False
)
```

I am using this snippet to save the model on Colab

```
import torch

torch.save(model.state_dict(), FILENAME)
```

Then load it on my local CPU using

```
# Initiating an instance of the model type

model_reload = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained(
    "bert-base-cased",
    num_labels=len(tag2idx),
    output_attentions = False,
    output_hidden_states = False
)

# Loading the model
model_reload.load_state_dict(torch.load(FILENAME, map_location='cpu'))
model_reload.eval()
```

The code snippet used to tokenize the text and make actual predictions is the same both on the Colab GPU notebook instance and my CPU notebook instance.

**Expected Behavior**

The GPU-trained model behaves correctly and classifies the following tokens perfectly:

```
O       [CLS]
O       Good
O       morning
O       ,
O       my
O       name
O       is
B-per   John
I-per   Kennedy
O       and
O       I
O       am
O       working
O       at
B-org   Apple
O       in
O       the
O       headquarters
O       of
B-geo   Cupertino
O       [SEP]
```

**Actual Behavior**

When loading the model and use it to make predictions on my CPU, the predictions are totally wrong:

```
I-eve   [CLS]
I-eve   Good
I-eve   morning
I-eve   ,
I-eve   my
I-eve   name
I-eve   is
I-geo   John
B-eve   Kennedy
I-eve   and
I-eve   I
I-eve   am
I-eve   working
I-eve   at
I-gpe   Apple
I-eve   in
I-eve   the
I-eve   headquarters
I-eve   of
B-org   Cupertino
I-eve   [SEP]
```

Does anyone have ideas why it doesn't work? Did I miss something?

Comment: Can you please share your `state_dict` with us?

Comment: There are two other questions regarding saving and loading transformer models leading to worse accuracy ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64666510/huggingface-transformers-low-accuracy-after-load-custom-pretrained-model-in-a-t) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64663385/saving-and-reload-huggingface-fine-tuned-transformer)). I think you should open a bug report.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed it, there were two problems:

1. The index-label mapping for tokens was wrong, for some reason the `list()` function worked differently on Colab GPU than my CPU (??)
2. The snippet used to save the model was not correct, for models based on the huggingface-transformers library you can't use `model.save_dict()` and load it later, you need to use the `save_pretrained()` method of your model class, and load it later using `from_pretrained()`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Other Scenarios

I had the same issue with my **custom model** initialized with `BertModel` from the Hugging-Face transformers library. Indeed, I had the first problem mentioned by [flyingjapans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13364419/flyingjapans) but with the `set()` method, which I used to get unique labels and then encode them dynamically.

```py
unique_labels = set([label for label in data["token_labels"].values for label in labels])
label2id = {k: v for v, k in enumerate(unique_labels)}
id2label = {v: k for v, k in enumerate(unique_labels)}
```

The problem is that at each time I run the notebook, `unique_labels` contains the labels in a different order compared to the previous notebook session, so I end up with different encoding of the labels.

It should be noted that the problem occurred even when:

1. Using the standard `BertForTokenClassification` model from the Hugging-Face transformers library while using `save_pretrained()` and `from_pretrained()`. However, It is recommended to save and load the best model using `save_pretrained()` and `from_pretrained()` respectively.
2. Running the notebook on the local host.

So just try to avoid using `set()` or **sort its output before label encoding**, thus you always end up with the same label encoding.